# R efficient lookup of values in DataFrame column

Tags: r, search, dataframe, lookup

I have a large R dataframe on which I need to look up rows based on two columns $start and $end efficiently many times. I imagine that the typical solution is O(N):

```
data[data$start <= start & data$end >= end, 1]
```

I would prefer to sort at least one of the columns and do more efficient O(log(N)) lookups. What inbuilt R methods exist to take advantage of ordering in a dataframe for lookup?

Comment: You could try the package `data.table`

Comment: Are you actually finding this slow?  How much data do you have?

Comment: Since index lookups and subsetting are generally fast enough not to be a code bottleneck, it would be useful to provide a reproducible example with timings.

Comment: I've managed without indexes for now, but to answer the questions. I was working with a table of 300000 rows or ~500 tables of 500 rows and 10^7 range lookups. I will try out `data.table` the next time I have to run this code.

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this is an old question. Just wanted to provide a link for those who come searching for fast lookups in R.

[Lookup performance in R](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/03/lookup-performance-in-r.html) - Joseph Adler. I find it to be quite comprehensive for my needs. He advocates the double bracket notation (`[[`) and provides time comparisons for multiple alternatives.

Comment: how would you get the entire row in the data frame using [[ ?